# How to subclass an automatically generated ObjectContext

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-4

I generated a database first ObjectContext using EF 4.3 in VS 2010. Then I used this class (and relating classes) in a Windows.Forms application.

This time want to use the same application with minor additions to some forms and an additional table (and a FK to it) to create a new application. Since I want to manage both projects at the same time, I created a new solution for second application, which subclasses the necessary forms and classes.

But I don't know how to use this technique for the ObjectContext I generated before. If I use an automatically generated new ObjectContext this will be a new class, therefore I have to recompile all the two solutions whenever I apply a change (I don't even mention the necessary assembly reference changes).

Manually creating a subclass of the aforementioned ObjectContext is not possible I guess if I don't do csdl/mdl/ssdl tricks manually.

I want to avoid creating an interface class between my code and the ObjectContext, because of the changes needed and lack of time to achieve.

Does anybody have an idea?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you misunderstanding some concepts in software development process.
This:

> Since I want to manage both projects at the same time, I created a new
>   solution for second application, which subclasses the necessary forms
>   and classes

is a very bad idea.

In fact, new functionality brings you to new *version* of your software.
Do not inherit anything. Just make a development branch (in terms of source control) for your previous project version, and continue to develop new version, extending functionality.

This will allow you to get two, completely independent versions of your software, which you will support simultaneously.

Comment: Thanks for your prompt answer Dennis. This approach solves _almost_ all my problems. But it creates a merge job between two branches, if a change affects the other branch. Actually new solution is in the same directory on the disk and SVN. The new solution is just a reorder of the previous one with some additions. But I'll take your approach into account seriously.

Comment: @user1667555: branches have to be *independent* from each other. The main disadvantage is that you have two versions - there can be similar bugs and similar new functional. But, I think, it is less harmful, then interdependency between two projects.